# Identify ARIMA model

Tags: arima

I have a question regarding identify ARIMA.
Is ARIMA(1,0,1) same as ARMA(1,1)?
Also $Y_t = 2Y_{t-1}-Y_{t-2}+e_t$
Is this both ARIMA(0,1,1) and IMA(1,1)?
Then if I were to ask identify ARIMA, is this mean just to find as specific as possible?
And what about this?
$Y_t = .5Y_{t-1}-.5Y_{t-2}+e_t-.5e_{t-1}+.25e_{t-2}$
Is this just ARIMA(2,0,3)?

Comment: Without going into details, what you say is correct except for the final point; $$Y_{t}=.5Y_{t-1}-.5Y_{t-2}+e_{t}-.5e_{t-1}+.25e_{t-2}$$ is _just_ ARIMA(2,0,2). To see this more clearly, write out an ARIMA(2,0,0) model - equivalently an AR(2) model - and then add MA terms.

Answer (score 0):

A short answers to your questions are:

> Is ARIMA(1,0,1) same as ARMA(1,1)?

Yes, ARIMA(p,d,q) = ARMA(p,q) when d=0

> Also $Y_t = 2Y_{t−1} − Y_{t−2} + e_t$
>   Is this both ARIMA(0,1,1) and IMA(1,1)?

No, this is an ARIMA(0,2,0)

> Then if I were to ask identify ARIMA, is this mean just to find as specific as possible?

Identification of ARIMA model is finding the best $p,d,q$ order for $ARIMA(p,d,q)$, using sample ACF and PACF.